# In Ruby, what is the best way to convert alphanumeric entries to integers for a column of a CSV containing a huge number of rows?

Tags: ruby, csv

My CSV contains about 60 million rows. The 10th column contains some alphanumeric entries, some of which repeat, that I want to convert into integers with a one-to-one mapping. That is, I don't want the same entry in `Original.csv` to have multiple corresponding integer values in `Processed.csv`. So, initially, I wrote the following code:

```
require 'csv'
udids = []
CSV.open('Original.csv', "wb") do |csv|
    CSV.foreach('Processed.csv', :headers=>true) do |row|
         unless udids.include?(row[9])
            udids << row[9]
         end
         udid = udids.index(row[9]) + 1
         array = [udid]
    csv<<array
  end
end
```

But, the program was taking a lot of time, which I soon realized was because it had to check all the previous rows to make sure only the new values get assigned a new integer value, and the existing ones are not assigned any new value.

So, I thought of hashing them, because when exploring the web about this issue, I learnt that hashing is faster than sequential comparing, somehow (I have not read the details about the how, but anyway...) So, I wrote the following code to hash them:

```
arrayUDID=[]
arrayUser=[]
arrayHash=[]
array1=[]

f = File.open("Original.csv", "r")
f.each_line { |line|
    row = line.split(",");
    arrayUDID<<row[9]
    arrayUser<<row[9]
}

arrayUser = arrayUser.uniq
arrayHash = []

for i in 0..arrayUser.size-1
    arrayHash<<arrayUser[i]
    arrayHash<<i
end

hash = Hash[arrayHash.each_slice(2).to_a]

array1=hash.values_at *arrayUDID

logfile = File.new("Processed.csv","w")
for i in 0..array1.size-1
    logfile.print("#{array1[i]}\n")
end
logfile.close
```

But here again, I observed that the program was taking a lot of time, which I realized must be due to the hash array (or hash table) running out of memory.

So, can you kindly suggest any method that will work for my huge file in a reasonable amount of time? By reasonable amount, I mean within 10 hours, because I realize that it's going to take some hours at least as it took about 5 hours to extract that dataset from an even bigger dataset. So, with my aforementioned codes, it was not getting finished even after 2 days of running the programs. So, if you can suggest a method which can do the task by leaving the computer on overnight, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: So, you have a csv file that you want to read , strip non-numeric characters from one of the columns  and write out to a output.csv?

Comment: Yes. I want to convert all the long, alphanumeric entries into simple positive integers.

Comment: Its only reading , I dont see any conversion

Comment: Could you add an example of the data you're starting with vs. the data you want to end up with?  Are you saying you have rows with alphanumeric entries like `a2f04213bfsz42` and you want to convert them to simple integers, but the same alphanumeric string can occur multiple times and if so it must map to the same positive integer?

Comment: @NullSoulException Its converting, and writing into the new file. That's what its doing, trust me, albeit slowly as the number of rows increases, which is the issue.

Comment: @etdev Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
udids = {}
unique_count = 1

output_csv = CSV.open("Processed.csv", "w")

CSV.foreach("Original.csv").with_index do |row, i|
  output_csv << row and next if i == 0 # skip first row (header info)
  val = row[9]
  if udids[val.to_sym]
    row[9] = udids[val.to_sym]
  else
    udids[val.to_sym] = unique_count
    row[9] = unique_count
    unique_count += 1
  end
  output_csv << row
end

output_csv.close
```

The performance depends heavily on how many duplicates there are (the more the better), but basically it keeps track of each value as a key in a hash, and checks to see if it has encountered that value yet or not.  If so, it uses the corresponding value, and if not it increments a counter, stores that count as the new value for that key and continues.

I was able to process a 10 million line test CSV file in about 3 minutes.

Comment: Wow! That worked! Could you please explain some parts of the code that I am struggling to understand, if you don't mind? (1) `udids` was declared as a hash in the first line. Then how does it work like an array in `udids[val.to_sym]`? (2) In that line, why are you converting the values into symbols? What's the purpose of it? (3) In a hash, there is supposed to be a key+value pair, right? So is that what happens with `udids[val.to_sym]`? Does that line create a value+symbol pair that works like a hash? (4) What is the result of `if udids[val.to_sym]`? Is it true/false or something else? Thanks.

Comment: q: how does it work like an array in udids[val.to_sym]? a: It doesn't work like an array. It works like a hash. q: why are you converting the values into symbols? a: Symbols are less noisy and immutable. It's generally a good idea to use them. q:  there is supposed to be a key+value pair, right? So is that what happens with udids[val.to_sym]? a: It happens here: `udids[val.to_sym] = unique_count` q: What is the result of if udids[val.to_sym]? a: It's an integer >= 1. Please accept etdev's answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @seph Done. In question 1, I meant that hashes are supposed to have curly braces(`{}`), but in that statement, it has big bracket (`[]`). That's why I asked the question, because this is new for me. So, your comment "It doesn't work like an array; it works like a hash" was unhelpful in that, you didn't elaborate how. Because he didn't write `udids{val.to_sym}`; he wrote `udids[val.to_sym]`, which looks like the element `val.to_sym` of the array `udids[]`. But there is no array `udids[]`; there is only a hash `udids{}`. But, anyway, thanks for clarifications of the other 3 questions I had.

Comment: @user5346597 Thanks for accepting my answer.  The [`[]` syntax](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) is the basic way to get the value of a hash at a given key.  So if you have a hash like `my_hash = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`, then `my_hash[:a]` will return `1`, `my_hash[:b]` will return `2` etc.  You can also set values by doing e.g. `my_hash[:d] = 4`. I hope that answers your question.  Also I chose to use a hash because hash lookups take constant time, whereas array lookups take O(N) time (because you have to iterate through the array until you find the value).